# Unable to push docker image to GitHub Packages

Tags: docker, github-actions, github-package-registry

I am unable to publish docker image to GitHub Packages.

Although I have followed the instructions found here:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-docker-images#publishing-images-to-github-packages

```
name: HazelCast
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'
    tags:
      - v*.*.*
    paths:
      - dev/hazelcast/**

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: company/group/application/hazelcast

jobs:
  docker:
    name: Build HazelCast Docker Image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
      - name: Login to GitHub Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ secrets.APP_WRITE_USER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.APP_WRITE_TOKEN }}
      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v5
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}
      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          context: dev/hazelcast
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

This builds fine, and it looks like it pushed the docker image.

```
#8 pushing manifest for ghcr.io/company/group/application/hazelcast:master@sha256:ff4a7ebfbfbed7b76e905ed3875388cf60f6500c0b6721495efae1a7cf1238fd 1.4s done
#8 DONE 2.2s
```

Although the Docker image is not in GitHub packages.

I even tried to build it manually with docker command.

```
      - name: Build docker image
        run: |
          docker build --no-cache \
            --label org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/company/application-hazelcast \
            --label org.opencontainers.image.version=latest \
            --label org.opencontainers.image.title=hazelcast \
            -t ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}:latest ./.
          docker inspect ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}:latest
          docker push ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}:latest
```

But still, it pushed the docker image, but the image is not listed in project packages.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled write privileges for GitHub Packages? From the GH docs link you referenced:

```
permissions:
     contents: read
     packages: write
```

You can also handle this when you create/modify a GHA API key.

Comment: In the YAML workflow file? I have tried in two different projects to publish this docker image. On the second project I tried I am already publishing a Spring Boot docker image with Java, Spring Boot and Buildpacks. That is published just fine. That published docker image is available in GitHub Packages for the project. When I tried to add a new workflow to build another docker image with HazelCast too, it would not publish it.

Comment: The TOKEN I am using has write permissions to the organization GitHub Packages. I have been using it to publish other docker images in other projects.